# flutter meaning of () for various widgets

Tags: flutter, syntax

Ofter times in flutter I come across () used in the code, and I've just been rote memorizing when they need to be there. However, I don't exactly understand what they mean, or even what they are called.

Some examples:

```
setState((){count++})

FlatButton(child: Text("More Beer"), 
           onPressed: ()=> sendBeer())   // <-- I'm also interested if the two ()'s mean different things.
```

for sendBeer(), I would call the () and indication that sendBeer is a function, and that it takes no arguments.  Is that different from () by itself?

In short, can you explain what "()" in those examples are, what they are called, and what they mean?  [Also, sometimes I see it as `(_)` or even `(_,_,_)` ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unrelated to widgets/flutter. It is the syntax for defining closures, which are functions as variables.

There are two syntaxes available:

```dart
() => value;
```

and

```
() {
  return value;
}
```

Where `()` represents the arguments of your function. It doesn't have to be strictly `()` and could be something more complex:

```dart
final example = (int variable, {String namedParameter}) => print($variable $namedParameter');
```

Which is equivalent to:

```dart
void example(int variable, {String namedParameter}) {
  print($variable $namedParameter');
}
```

Comment: I'm new to flutter and dart too. Just curious, what does the syntax `{String namedParameter}` mean here?

Comment: For closures that have underscores such as (_) or (_,_,_) does that just indicate that the closure has generic variables? Edit:  it appears underscores don't show up in comments.  it should be "(underscore) or (underscore,underscore,underscore) at the beginning of this comment.

Comment: What do you mean by underscores? None of your examples have underscores

Comment: I edited my question because the underscores didn't show up in text view, only code view.  it's at the very end of the question

Comment: It's a convention for when we don't care about the closure parameter

Comment: so () is equivalent to (underscore,underscore) ?